# how to pass param props to redux container

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a selector that needs an id from user, this would ideally come from params.

localhost:3001/users/1

**selector**

```
export const getPosts = () => // this gets all posts
  createSelector(
    postSelector,
    (state) => state.posts,
 );

export const getUserPosts = (params) =>
    createSelector(
        postSelector,
        state => state.posts.filter(user => user.userId === params.userId)
    )
```

how would i pass the params to the container component.

**container**

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { createStructuredSelector } from "reselect";
import Profile from "./../components/profile/profile"
import { getUserPosts } from "./../selectors/selectors";

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
    posts: getUserPosts(), // how do i pass params within this selector
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    null,
)(Profile);
```

Considering the container logic is seperated from the component.

**Profile**

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
export interface IProps {
    match?: any
}
class Profile extends Component<IProps, {}> {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.match.params) // this needs to be passed to container
        return (
            <div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Profile;
```

Ideally you can add the container logic to the Profile component, but that would look like an anti pattern as the component is always followed by a container.

Comment: can you add the code for `postSelector`? I'm just interested in the arguments and the return value of it

Comment: ok i updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `mapStateToProps` as a function has access to those props as its  [second argument](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#ownprops-optional) because the match object is a prop of the container that gets passed down to `Profile`. Or in other words **without `reselect`** this is easily done like:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
   return {
       posts: state.posts.filter(post => post.userId === ownProps.match.params.userId)
   }
}
```

---

When it comes to `reselect`, **I haven't used it**, but I think [this](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#accessing-react-props-in-selectors) part on the reselect README should help you.

If I read it correctly, what you need to do is write your selector in a way that it has `props` as its second argument. Those props should be passed from `mapStateToProps` to the selector the same way the `state` argument is.

Not sure if just doing this will help:

```js
export const getUserPosts =
    createSelector(
        postSelector,
        state, ownProps => state.posts.filter(post => post.userId === ownProps.match.params.userId)
    )

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
    posts: getUserPosts,
});
```

Maybe the `postSelector` needs changing.

---

Also, as a fallback, I think your current code might work as:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
   return {
       posts: getUserPosts(ownProps.match.params)(state)
   }
}
```

Comment: will give this a shot, and let you know how it went.

Answer (score 0):

This was the logic i was able to implement that got it working with selector.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => createStructuredSelector({
    posts: getUserPosts(ownProps.match.params),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

index.js

```
interface Props {
    jobIds: string[],
    namespace: string,
    jobStateType: string
}

export class IncompleteJobsListComponent extends React.PureComponent<Props> {
    render() {
        const { jobIds, namespace, jobStateType } = this.props;
        const flex = jobIds.length ? 0 : 1;
        return (
            <FlatList
                contentContainerStyle={{ flex }}
                ListEmptyComponent={
                    <IncompleteJobsListConfirmationScreen
                        namespace={namespace}
                    />
                }
                data={jobIds}
                keyExtractor={item => `${item}`}
                refreshControl={<IncompleteJobsRefreshControl />}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                    <JobListItem documentSetId={item} first={index === 0} jobStateType={jobStateType} />
                )}
            />
        );
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
    jobIds: selectIds
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(IncompleteJobsListComponent);
```

selector.js

```
const selectJobStateType = () => (_state, props) => props.jobStateType;


const makeSelectJobStateTypeValue = () => createDeepEqualSelector(
    selectJobStateType(),
    jobStateType => jobStateType
)

const selectFilteredData = createDeepEqualSelector(
    [selectDenormalizedDocumentSetsArray, makeSelectSearch(), makeSelectJobStateTypeValue()],
    (denormalizedDocumentSetsArray, searchTerm, jobStateType) => {
        const fltered = denormalizedDocumentSetsArray.filter(availableJobs => {
            return (jobStateType === 'READY' ? availableJobs.jobState === 'READY' : availableJobs.jobState === 'IN_PROGRESS');
        })

        return search(fltered, searchTerm, [
            'schemaName',
            'varietyName',
            'event.entity._hierarchy',
            'event.pickTypeName'
        ])
    }
);
```